# AWS VS Azure , which one is preferable for SQL Server 2012 standard version?

Tags: sql-server, replication, amazon-rds, azure-sql-database, aws

I want few recommendations while considering azure vs aws for our current database which is SQL Server 2012 standard edition.
Currently we are using AWS RDS for managing our database, recently we had been considering active read replica for our heavy prod database, but it seems like aws doesn't have read replica option for MS SQL Server , but only CDC(change data Capture ) option , that doesn't solve our needs because CDC involves manual loading of every other thing except for tables and their primary indexes, whereas for Aurora or mySQL , they have proper read replica options.
Hence we want to know if MS Azure will be better for us in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Azure SQL Database you have the option of Geo-Replication. Active geo-replication enables you to configure up to four readable secondary databases in the same or different data center locations (regions). Secondary databases are available for querying and for failover if there is a data center outage or the inability to connect to the primary database. The failover must be initiated manually by the application of the user. After failover, the new primary has a different connection end point. You can learn more about this Azure SQL Database feature [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview).

Comment: I agree that if you want these awesome features go Azure. Just keep in mind it is SQL 2017 not SQL 2012. But you should go there anyway.